# Java 8 Streams - Apply fixed amount of predicate filters to single Stream

Tags: java, java-stream, predicate

Is there a way to apply fixed amount of `Predicates` to an opened `Stream` ? I really can't get any attempt of mine to work. Either the attempt ends up with stream closed error or not all filters are applied.

Example:

```
 // list of all JLabels of any container
private final List<JLabel> listOfLabels = new ArrayList<>();
// set of user-defined filters
private final Set<Predicate<JLabel>> filters = new HashSet<>();

// let's add some filters
filters.add(label -> label.getBackground() == Color.RED);
filters.add(label -> label.getWidth() > 500);
```

How can I apply all filter to the Stream of `listOfFiles` ? Let's say we want to hide `JLabels` NOT matching these filters. I am looking for something like a non-working code snippet below.

```
public void applyFilters() {
   listOfLabels.forEach(label -> label.setVisible(false)); // hide all labels
   Stream<JLabel> stream = listOfLabels.stream();
   filters.forEach(stream::filter);
   stream.forEach(label -> label.setVisible(true));
   // stream closed error
}
```

After method `applyFilters()` is executed, the container should have visible only labels matching all predicates defined by `filters` set. (red background and width greater than 500 in this example).

Comment: `filters.stream().reduce(Predicate::or)` (or `Predicate::and`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
public void applyFilters() {
    listOfLabels.forEach(label -> label.setVisible(false));
    listOfLabels.stream()
        .filter(label -> filters.stream()
            .allMatch(predicate -> predicate.test(label)))
        .forEach(label -> label.setVisible(true));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you work with Stream you have to always use the link to Stream object that was return by applying previous operation. 
As you can see from the API:

```
Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate);
```

The Stream object is returned and javadoc says:

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream that match
>        * the given predicate.

Having this in mind, in your case, we can apply something like the following:

Convert:

```
filters.forEach(stream::filter);
```

To:

```
   for (Predicate<JLabel> filter : filters) {
        stream = stream.filter(filter);
   }
```

That should work, since now you update the link to the Stream object and follow documentation.

Comment: Thank you for working answer as well as explanation, but I prefer functional style and code you provided, unfortunately, cannot be rewritten to functional style.

Answer (score 2):

You can first reduce all your filters to a single filter via the `Predicate::and` operator:

```
Predicate<JLabel> allFilters = filters.stream()
    .reduce(Predicate::and)
    .orElse(t -> true);
```

Then, fliter using this reduced filter:

```
listOfLabels.forEach(label -> label.setVisible(false));

listOfLabels.stream()
    .filter(allFilters)
    .forEach(label -> label.setVisible(true));
```

For this last step, you might also want to take a slightly different approach:

```
listOfLabels.forEach(label -> label.setVisible(allFilters.test(label)));
```

This has the advantage to need only one pass over the labels.